# Tensorflow Lite demo app with ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco model crashes with input shape mismatch

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I am working on tensorflow object detection with pretrained model `ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco_2019_08_14` I have some doubt.

1)I am trying to use `ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco`. I am facing an issue as v1 model takes input as 300X300 and v3 taking 320x320. How can we solve this error? I tried some method as changing `TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED` as false and using it as float. Still no luck.

2)I don't have `labelmap.txt` file for v3.

3)For `coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant_2018_06_29` model in the sample example project. In `download_model.gradle` there is a web link from where v1 model is getting downloaded.
http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant_2018_06_29.zip
Any idea from where I can get similar link for latest `ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco_2019_08_14` for `download_model.gradle`? Where I can keep similar link and download the zip file and store v3 model and download repository from the server?

Thank you.